# Unmask input before persisting to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input field that is masked `mm:ss`. 
What I want to do is unmask this input and convert those numbers to seconds only
`(mm)*60+ss` and then persist to database as such.
How do I achieve this?
This is my input field:

```
<input class="form-control  input-lg time" name="run" type="text" 
placeholder="__ min : __ sec" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".time").mask("99 min : 99 sec", {
        placeholder: "__ min : __sec"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate it using a regular expression to get the four digits you're expecting, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".time").mask("99 min : 99 sec", {
        placeholder: "__ min : __sec"
    }).change(function(){
        // Find contiguous numbers in pairs
        var pairs = this.value.match(/\d{2}/g);
        // You expect two pairs
        if(pairs.length === 2){
            console.log(Number(pairs[0]) * 60 + Number(pairs[1]));
        }
    });
});
```

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/f09n1gch/1/

If you want to overwrite it before sending it to the server, you can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".time").mask("99 min : 99 sec", {
        placeholder: "__ min : __sec"
    });
    $("form").submit(function(){
        var $time = $(".time");
        // Find contiguous numbers in pairs
        var pairs = $time.val().match(/\d{2}/g);
        // You expect two pairs
        if(pairs.length === 2){
            $time.unmask().val(Number(pairs[0]) * 60 + Number(pairs[1]));
        }else{
            console.log('You should input four digits');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/f09n1gch/2/

Comment: This works great!Thank you.
But instead of writing it on the console, how do I persist it to the db with the given value ?
the name field in  input corresponds to the name of the column in the database, and gets posted using Spring as backend.
So how do I make it that this is the value it takes ? Not the value written as in the placeholder ?

Comment: Really hard to figure this out without knowing more about your DB and setup. Whatever you're doing to send to the database, run this code first and send the resulting value.

Comment: Oh, ok. Then you should execute that code right before sending the value to the server. I'll edit my answer to give you an idea

Comment: Thank you!
I did it by calling document.getElementById("").value= (and changing value to the result )

Comment: Sure, glad it worked! I just gave you a jQuery answer because you were using it

Answer (score 1):

The mask plugin has `.cleanVal()`, a method for unmasking the value:

```
    $("form").on('submit', function(e) {
      var x = $('.time').cleanVal();
      var min = Number(x.substring(0, x.length/2));
      var sec = Number(x.slice(x.length/2));
      console.log(60 * min + sec);
    });
```

See [the docs](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#getting-a-masked-value-programmatically) for details.